# DataTable pagination is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination, datatables

I have my html page which contains a table. I use dataTable plugin for pagination.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2C1e.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2C1e.png)https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

My html as follows.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">

table, th,td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
#clients_data {
margin-bottom:100px;
}
</style> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<title>Clients</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 100%" id="clients_data" class="display" >
        <caption>Clients</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Clients</th>
                <th>Number of Sites</th>
                <th>Reset the Processing</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%" id="machines_data">
        <caption>Machines</caption>
        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            loadCustomers();
            loadMachines();

        });

        function loadCustomers() {
            $
                    .ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/cache/getCustomers',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function(data) {
                            var rows = [];
                            $
                                    .each(
                                            data,
                                            function(id, value) {
                                                rows
                                                        .push(' <tbody><tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client='
                                                                + id
                                                                + '">'
                                                                + id
                                                                + '</td><td>'
                                                                + value
                                                                + '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset(\''
                                                                + id
                                                                + '\')">Reset</td></tr> </tbody>');
                                            });
                            $('#clients_data').append(rows.join(''));
                            $('#clients_data').DataTable({
                                "pagingType" : "full_numbers"
                            });

                        }
                    });
        };
.......
```

this loads data, but pagination is not working. means when I set 10 entries per page, it shows all entries..I have attached the screenshot. AM i missing any other plugin?
But in the mentioned tutorial, it says I need to use **"pagingType" : "full_numbers"** attribute only..
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pagination works perfectly as expected. The problem is that you wrongly insert a `<tbody>` section for each row. And since you only can have one `<tbody>` per DataTable the shown pagination will be based on the very first row in the dataset, thus always showing one page in total.

You could do this instead :

```
rows
  .push(' <tr><td><a href="clientSiteInfo.html?client=' +
    id +
    '">' +
    id +
    '</td><td>' +
    value +
    '</td><td><button type="button" onclick="reset(\'' +
    id +
    '\')">Reset</td></tr> ');
});
```

and

```
$('#clients_data').append('<tbody>'+rows.join('')+'</tbody>');
```

but you should really consider using [**`columns`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) instead.

Comment: One more simple question..I have done same for all my html pages. (means, datatable settings, which are linked to this main page) But im not seeing any dataTable pagination in other pages..What im doing wrong?

Comment: @Ratha, It is hard to say without knowing more. Is the datatable initialised correct? I.e is there a search box for example? Do you set `paging` to false (you should not)? Do you set `pagingType` to some odd value? `full_numbers` is the default so you really not need set it.  When you insert data programmatically as you do, you have the risk that you by accident initialize the table *before* data is constructed, are you sure the table is initialized *after* you insert a `<tbody>` (or what you do) to the other tables?